# Why does typescript have a limitation with using custom symbols in interfaces?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Here is a simple program:

```
const mySymbol = Symbol();
interface Fails {
  [mySymbol]: boolean;
}

interface Succeeds {
  [Symbol.hasInstance]: boolean;
}
```

And here is the output from compling:

```
$ tsc --lib es6 odd.ts
odd.ts(3,3): error TS1169: A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol.
```

The error is understandable, that only built-in symbols can be used as Typescript interface property types, but this seems like an arbitrary limitation.

Can someone explain why this limitation exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider some code:

```
// Implementation not visible to us
declare function getSymbol(): Symbol;

const s1 = getSymbol();
const s2 = getSymbol();

interface Type1 {
  [s1]: string;
  [s2]: number;
}
```

Is this declaration legal? Let's ask some friends.

*Alice* says **yes**, because `getSymbol` returns a different symbol each time it's invoked, so `s1` and `s2` create two separate property slots.

*Bob* says **no**, because `getSymbol` always returns the same symbol each time it's invoked, so `s1` and `s2` are conflicting declarations for the same property.

*Eve* says **hahaha**, because `getSymbol` randomly returns one of two different symbols, so who knows what's going on.

Who's right? I have no idea. No one does. We're all just speculating, because we can't see the implementation of `getSymbol`. Even if we could, its implementation could be arbitrarily complex.

Moreover, even if we could describe `getSymbol`'s behavior, we still can't account for this code:

```
// Implementations not visible to us
declare function getSymbol1(): Symbol;
declare function getSymbol2(): Symbol;

const s1 = getSymbol1();
const s2 = getSymbol2();

interface Type1 {
  [s1]: string;
  [s2]: number;
}
```

Maybe `getSymbol1` and `getSymbol2` return the same symbol. Maybe they don't. Maybe they sometimes do. Who knows? Without a way to unambiguously name individual Symbol *instances*, it's an unsolvable puzzle. But type systems, especially structural ones, are pretty bad at describing instance identity. You could have some system where you name each symbol instance, but you're still left without a way to describe a function that returns a new symbol on each invocation. In general you're going to have a really hard time with code like the first snippet because a type system is going to assume that the same function, invoked twice, produces two objects which are effectively identical.

Comment: Thanks! Makes perfect sense.

Comment: Presumably though, well known Symbols like hasInstance are just known by the compiler. And I guess it is assumed that no funny business is going on with them where they are reassigned.

Comment: Correct - the declared members of the `Symbol` object are assumed to be "normal" in that regard